# Finding angular velocity of object moving in a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

> An object moving in a circle makes $15 \text{ revolutions per minute}$. What is its angular velocity?

I know that the equation for angular velocity is $\omega = \frac vr$.

I also know that $1 \text{ minute}$ is $60 \text{ seconds}$.

However I do not know how to use this information to find the angular velocity as the radius is not given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\omega=2\pi v$ where $v$ is frequency, and $\omega$ is angular velocity.

$v$=Number of revolutions in $1$ second =$15/60=1/4$.    {Since object is making $15$ revolutions in $60$ seconds}

So, $\omega=2\pi v=\frac{2\pi}{4}=\pi/2 $ radians/sec which is approximately $1.57$ radians/sec

Comment: Could the answer be in S^-1 ? So w = 1.6 [s^-1] ?

Comment: Yes @Dan, I have mentioned in the answer that ω=1.57  radians/sec which is approximately 1.6 radians/sec.

Comment: Or should it be 1.6[rads^-1]

Comment: Unit of angular velocity is radians/sec, so answer will be 1.6 radians/sec.

Answer (score 1):

Angular velocity is measured in radians per second, so that $15$ revolutions per minute becomes $$\frac{15\times 2\pi}{60}$$

Comment: Is w = 1.6 [s^-1] correct ?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians per second